# How to calculate $E[|X-a|]$

Tags: probability, expected-value

How to calculate $E[|X-a|]$

The only known relation I know are the following:
$E[X+a] = E[X] + a$

Also: $E[|X|] \geq |E[X]|$
However this gives:
$E[|X-a|] \geq |E[X-a]| = |E[X]|-a$

Is this correct? Or is there a different way? The random variable $X$ is continuous.

Comment: Your last equality relies on the fact that $|a-b|=|a|-b$ which is definitely not true for all $a,b\in\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

Split into two cases and use the law of total probability:
\begin{align}
E[|X-a|] 
&= E[|X-a| \mid X-a > 0]P[X-a > 0] + E[|X-a| \mid X-a \le 0]P[X-a \le 0] \\
&= E[X-a \mid X>a]P[X>a] + E[a-X \mid X \le a]P[X\le a]
\end{align}

Comment: $E(|X-a| \mid X-a>0)$ is not equal to $E(X-a)$.

Comment: @grand_chat Indeed.  I got carried away.  Corrected now.